# Imperative sentence dataset for building POS tagger

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to build POS tagger on my own for imperative sentences.

Till now I have tried following code in python for POS tagging using nltk:

```
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
text = word_tokenize("open app and play movie")
print(nltk.pos_tag(text))
```

Output:

```
[('open', 'JJ'), ('app', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('play', 'VB'), ('movie', 'NN')]
```

It is wrongly classifying verb as adjective in case of "open". I searched a lot and there are many solutions available to it. One of them is building your own POS tagger.

All of my sentences are imperative sentences. I want to build POS tagger on imperative sentences. 
If any imperative sentences dataset is available that would be of great help to train my POS tagger to properly classify.